# NSBatchUpdateRequest Updata is not working

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I had more than 6 data in core data. I want to update that image in core data using `NSBatchUpdateRequest` specifically.  For example, i click the button, it will open the new view and change the images then update the image, and so on.

My code :

```
var batchRequest = NSBatchUpdateRequest(entityName: NSStringFromClass(TimeScheduler.classForCoder()))
var error: NSError?

batchRequest.propertiesToUpdate = ["name": userName, "alarm": userAlarm]

batchRequest.resultType = .UpdatedObjectsCountResultType

var result = managedContext.executeRequest(batchRequest,
            error: &error) as NSBatchUpdateResult
        NSLog("Updated objects: \(result)")

if !managedContext.save(&error) {
    println("Could not save \(error), \(error?.userInfo)")           
}
```

Comment: Did you ever found the answer?